# How to skip test hook in pre-commit using the command line?

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I want to skip tests while running pre-commit. Right now I do `pre-commit` over my terminal which run all hooks.

Answer (score 3):

[the docs cover this case](https://pre-commit.com/#temporarily-disabling-hooks):

> Not all hooks are perfect so sometimes you may need to skip execution
> of one or more hooks. pre-commit solves this by querying a `SKIP`
> environment variable. The `SKIP` environment variable is a comma
> separated list of hook ids. This allows you to skip a single hook
> instead of `--no-verify`ing the entire commit.
>
> `$ SKIP=flake8 git commit -m "foo"`

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit